# Binomial distribution problem

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

There are 50 people in a room.Each person flips a unbiased coin only two times.If someone flips two heads in a row goes in the next room otherwise stays in the current room.What is the probability that at least  25 people will pass in the next room?

I am thinking that the solution is $P(X \geq 25)$ where $X$ is binomial distribution with parameters $X \sim B(50,1/4)$?

Am I correct ?

Comment: Very good! Now keep going!

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think $$\mathbb{P}(X \geq 25)= \sum_{I=25}^{50}{\displaystyle {\binom {N}{i}}p^{i}q^{N-i}}$$

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Notice that you want the event $X>25$, in  the comment above you compute $X \ge 5$

Comment: @leonbloy at least 25.This is what I meant.I am sorry.I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are practically done. Depending on the problem context, you can do several things

1. Compute numerically the binomial sum.
2. Use the fact that a Binomial with large $N$ approximates a normal distribution of same mean and variance, and compute the (approximate) probability as a gaussian integral (tail).
3. Bound it using for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

For the later: the Binomial has $\mu= N p = 12.5$ and $\sigma^2=Np(1-p)=9.375$, hence $\sigma=3.06$. Now $(25-\mu)/\sigma \approx 4$. Hence, you can readily assert that the probability will be very small. In particular, the (not tight) Chebyshev bound says that $p<1/16$

Comment: Can you assess the integral form of 2 case?